# Storing data in memory and inserting all vs inserting one by one

Tags: c#, web-services, oracle

I need to get data from service and insert it to database.
Here is some info about service: I have to get ids and get data according to that id from service. This operation is done once in a day. Data for about 10.000 IDs must be inserted every day. Needed time to get id list is approximately 20 seconds and getting data for that id varies from 0.5 to 9 seconds.

I have to options:

First option is:

1. Get all data from web service, store everything in List<>
2. Make some operations on that List<>
3. Open connection insert everything into database at once and then close the connection

   Code example:

   ```
   //Get datafrom service and store it List<> or some collection
   TestService client = new TestService();
   MyClass changedData;
   List<MyClass> serviceResult = new List<MyClass>();

   string[] changedDataIDs = client.GetChangedIDs();

   foreach (string id in changedDataIDs)
   {
       changedData = client.GetData(id);
       serviceResult.Add(changedData);
   }


   //Make some operttions on that data
   List<Person> persons = serviceResult.Perons......;

   //Insert everything into database at once
   string conString = "..";
   OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(conString);
   OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("MY_STORED_PROCEDURE", con);
   //Add parameters
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(....));
   .........

   try
   {
       con.Open();

       foreach (var item in collection)
       {
           //Give values to parameters
           cmd.Parameters[0] = item.value;
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }
   }
   finally
   {
       con.Close();
   }
   ```

Second option is:

1. Get data individually from service
2. Make needed operations on that data
3. Open connection insert data to database close connection and repeat steps

   Code example:

   ```
   //Get changed IDs from service
   TestService client = new TestService();
   string[] changedDataIDs = client.GetChangedIDs();
   MyClass changedData;
   Person changedPersonDetails;
   OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("MY_STORED_PROCEDURE");
   //Add parameters
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(....));
   .........

   foreach (string id in changedDataIDs)
   {
       //Get data individually from service
       changedData = client.GetData(id);

       //Make needed operations on that data
       changedPersonDetails = changedData.Person.........;

       //Give values to parameters
       cmd.Parameters[0] = changedPersonDetails.Contact...;

       //Open connection insert data to databse close connection
                   //ExecuteCommand is a method
       ExecuteCommand(cmd);
   }


   public int ExecuteCommand(OracleCommand cmd)
   {
       int affectedRowCount = 0;
       OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection("");
       cmd.Connection = con;

       try
       {
           con.Open();
           affectedRowCount = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }
       finally
       {
           con.Close();
       }

       return affectedRowCount;
   }
   ```

I think that bad side of first option is RAM consumption and bad side of second option is opening and closing connection to many times. Now I want to now that will storing to much data in List<> will cause to memory exception or C# will handle this? Which option should I use?

Comment: The answer to your question entirely depends on the amount of data you are dealing with.  Have you profiled both bits of code using representative data sets?

Comment: Instead of going to the service to retrieve the myClass data for every ID can you receive directly an array (or List) of your myClass for the changed ID? Less roundtrip to the service should boost performance. And for the connection problem is not a real problem with connection pooling active.

Comment: @Paolo can you please explain further?

Comment: @Steve no I have to retrieve data one by one by ID.

Answer (score 2):

Both seems not proper IMHO. When you insert one by one, no transaction is employed. What if one or more fail(s) and others are committed to database?

If you try to insert all in one operation, if one fails, all transaction will fail, then there will be no updates in the database (it is better to create a transaction, which you do not use in the code you have provided).

You may go with the best of both worlds; create smaller chunks, for example 100 items. Then try to insert these in a transaction. Then insert the other 100. If any of this transactions fail, just try to run the transaction again.

On the issue about RAM consumption; it just depends on the entities you are using, no one can point a direct answer.

Comment: I will insert them and catch exception, if error occurs I will write it to log and commit other successful inserts or updates